# How is Ultron different from JARVIS?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*,

> Ultron was termed as an AI (Artificial Intelligence). Okay, but why was everyone (Avengers and Nick Fury) scolding Tony for developing an AI in secret? Doesn't Marvel Cinematic Universe already have AI? JARVIS is a famous example of an AI. My theory was that Ultron simply had different morals than JARVIS. But, it turned out that Ultron was somehow special. How?

Note:

> I am not involving Mind Stone here. I am talking about the Ultron program only.

Later in the movie, we saw that

> Tony was able to boot JARVIS into Mind Stone's computational matrix. So, how is JARVIS not same as Ultron? How exactly is JARVIS not a real AI?

Comment: Isn't JARVIS just an elaborated version of Apple's Siri? It seems to me tha JARVIS only interacts with Tony Stark by giving him factual informations that are already in Stark's databases?

Comment: @Taladris - JARVIS knows sarcasm, jokes. For me that more than passes the Turing test.

Comment: Also, it is very efficient at information processing (even better than average humans). Even Stark asks him for solutions regarding a situation.

Comment: @Taladris That's how JARVIS started, but has since grown and gained more functionality (Stark says this himself in _Age of Ultron_, just without mentioning Siri)

Comment: i was quite disappointed that the usual Jarvis wit was missing from Age of Ultron,was hoping it would have been magnified by the vision.

Answer (score 20):

> why was everyone (Avengers and Nick Fury) scolding Tony for developing an AI in secret?

They weren’t. They were scolding him for developing an AI *designed to autonomously control robots that would encircle and protect the entire planet* in secret.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things here.

1. The Avengers weren't scolding Tony for developing an AI in secret. They were scolding him because he was experimenting with completely unknown sources in secret. He did not make any security checks before starting up the Ultron program. He directly used the Scepter to have a new consciousness. Thor is vocal about this when he yet again mentions that humans shouldn't meddle with things they do not comprehend(or something to that tune)
2. Ultron is different from JARVIS because only 1 of them was designed by Tony himself! Ultron wasn't designed by Tony, merely imported. Whereas Tony designed JARVIS from the scratch all by himself. The Avengers weren't so forthcoming with Vision either, despite knowing that he was after all a familiar face(?).
3. JARVIS wasn't originally designed as a true AI, as Tony says that he originally designed JARVIS to be a "Natural language UI".